# Strange traffic on my NAS, need to worry?

Tags: tor

My network structure is as follows: EDGE ROUTER -- SWITCH -- Synology NAS / PCs / AP

I forward L2TP/IPSec UDP ports 1701, 500, 4500 on my EDGE ROUTER to those ports on my NAS that is running VPN Server. I also use Synology DDNS for my public IP Address.

I have events like this happening in a daily basis: [image]

- Destination IP is my Synology NAS local IP, e.g. 192.168.0.7

Should I worry about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UDP port 123 is for NTP- Network Time Protocol. That IP is in the pool of public NTP servers. Your NAS is simply keeping its clock up to date.

Comment: Indeed, I use pool.ntp.org for time sync, I didn't know they used TOR relays in their pool. I'll move to time.nist.gov and see if this changes.